# What is the type of field excitation in a 775 DC motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, specifications

In a DC motor the types of field excitation are:

1. Shunt wound
2. Series wound
3. Permanent magnet

What is the type of excitation in a 775 DC motor?

[image]

*Image credit :* [DSD Motor](http://www.dsdmotor.com/ProductShow.asp?ID=271)

I also need to know the resistance, inductance and inertia of the motor.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. On this site we thank *afterwards* by upvoting useful answers and accepting the best one that answers the question.

Comment: Also 4. Hybrid wound (a combination of series and shunt wound).

Answer (score 1):

Tiny motors like that are permanent-magnet motors. Available two-winding  motors are much larger and are not widely available because permanent-magnet motors are taking over the market. The resistance can probably be assumed to be nominal voltage divided by stall current. Since the motors are not intended for high performance, the inductance and inertia will probably be difficult to determine. The seller or even the manufacturer may not have that information.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But can i get a website which tells me it is a permanent magnet or some type of datasheet which describes construction type

Comment: The web site link that you provided claims to be the manufacturer of the motor. It is unlikely that you will find more information elsewhere. Offers for email and chat help pop up constantly at that site. Have you tried them? The web page identifies the motor as brushed DC. I can assure you that the excitation is permanent magnet. Wound-field DC motors are not manufactured in such small sizes. I doubt that they have ever been manufactured in those sizes and production is declining in all sizes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a permanent magnet DC motor.

The following details are courtesy [Foneacc Motor](https://www.foneacc-motion.com/product/RS-775-Micro-dc-motor-foneacc-motion.html).

[image]